# Why doesn't screensaver start when I put computer to sleep?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, screensaver

When I click sleep mode on Windows 10, my screensaver doesn't start as expected. Is it possible to have the screen saver start upon sleep? Is this a bug? Or, is sleep mode not supposed to go to the screen saver?

Comment: When the computer is sleeping, the screen is "saved" by displaying no image at all.  Since the monitor is no longer receiving a video signal, the monitor can also enter a low-power state.

Answer (score 2):

When you put a computer to sleep, it goes into a "do nothing" state. It does not invoke the screen saver. [Explanation per Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions) below...

> Sleep is a power-saving state that allows a computer to quickly resume
>   full-power operation (typically within several seconds) when you want
>   to start working again. Putting your computer into the sleep state is
>   like pausing a DVD player—the computer immediately stops what it’s
>   doing and is ready to start again when you want to resume working.

Comment: So when will the screen saver ever be used? When I just let the computer go to sleep due to inactivity, it still doesn't invoke the screen saver.

Comment: The screen saver is set to "None" by default in Windows 10. Unless you have changed that setting, it won't start. Have you changed it?

Comment: BTW, you can find the screen saver settings by typing "screen saver" in the search box. It isn't in the normal place in Windows 10.

Comment: I have changed it. It still doesn't show up under any circumstance.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure that your screen saver kicks in before your machine goes to sleep.  If your sleep time triggers before your screen saver time, the screen saver can't launch.  So, maybe set your screen saver to 5 minutes and sleep to 10, something like that.

Comment: Question asks how to activate screensaver DURING sleep, and you answer how to activate it BEFORE sleep, that's different.